# Convert vector A into matrix M at values from vector B

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector

I have two vectors, both formatted as `double`. 
Vector "A" is mx2. The first column contains continuous timesteps and the second column data from a measurement series.

Vector "B" is a nx2 `(1<n<m)` and contains several timestamps which match to some of the timesteps in vector "A".

Now I want to split vector "A" into a matrix "M".
The Matrix should start a new column, each time, the timesteps of "A" corrspond with the timestamps in the first column in vector "B" and end when they correspond with the one in the second column.

So in each row of "B", the two timestamps define a column of the matrix "M".
As the sequences between two timestamps doesn't have the same length, every row should be filled up with 0 up to a fix row. For example row 5.
The matrix should only contain the measurement data and none of the timestamps. The matrix should be formatted as `double`.

In an example it would look like:

```
vector A [18 x 2]: 
1. column [11:13:30  11:13:31  11:13:32  11:13:33  11:13:34  11:13:35  11:13:36  11:13:37  11:13:38  11:13:39  11:13:40  11:13:41  11:13:42  11:13:43  11:13:44  11:13:45  11:13:46  11:13:47]
2. column [6000, 6500, 5000, 8000, 15000, 15500, 16000, 6000, 4000, 16500, 14000, 400, 5000, 6000, 9000, 12000, 13000, 5000]

vector B [3 x 2]: 
1. column [11:13:33  11:13:39  11:13:44]
2. column [11:13:36  11:13:40  11:13:46]

matrix M [3 x 6]: 
1. column [8000 15000 15500 16000 0]
2. column [16500 14000 0 0 0]
3. column [9000 12000 13000 0 0]
```

This seems like a quite complex thing to me and I hope anybody can help me with this.

Comment: @PranavTotala is suggesting an edit, he noticed that in the example `B` is smaller than `A`, but in the text it is written that they're the same size. Please fix your post.

Comment: Oh, sorry for that mistake. I just wanted to say, that `A` and `B` both have 2 columns but can differ in the amount of their rows. But of course they don't have the same size.

Comment: Are `A` and `B` cell arrays? Are the time stamps encoded as numeric values or strings?

Comment: `A` and `B` are formatted as `double`. Therefore, the timestamps in `B`, as well as the timeseries in `A`, are encoded as numeric value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code should do the job:

```
A = {
  '11:13:30'  6000;
  '11:13:31'  6500;
  '11:13:32'  5000;
  '11:13:33'  8000;
  '11:13:34' 15000;
  '11:13:35' 15500;
  '11:13:36' 16000;
  '11:13:37'  6000;
  '11:13:38'  4000;
  '11:13:39' 16500;
  '11:13:40' 14000;
  '11:13:41'   400;
  '11:13:42'  5000;
  '11:13:43'  6000;
  '11:13:44'  9000;
  '11:13:45' 12000;
  '11:13:46' 13000;
  '11:13:47'  5000
};

B = {
  '11:13:33' '11:13:36';
  '11:13:39' '11:13:40';
  '11:13:44' '11:13:46';
};

fill = 5;

% Obtain the computation parameters from A...
A_len = size(A,1);
A_seq = (1:A_len).';

% Find the breakpoints of A using the values in B...
idx_beg = ismember(A(:,1),B(:,1)) .* A_seq;
idx_beg = idx_beg(idx_beg > 0);
idx_end = ismember(A(:,1),B(:,2)) .* A_seq;
idx_end = idx_end(idx_end > 0);

%Compute the maximum number of elements per row...
rows = max(idx_end - idx_beg + 1);

% Adjust the fill in order to cover enough elements...
fill = max([fill rows]);

% Create the row indexers of A based on the breakpoints...
ran = arrayfun(@(x)idx_beg(x):idx_end(x),1:numel(idx_beg),'UniformOutput',false);

% Create the final matrix with zero-padding on the right...
mat = cellfun(@(x)[[A{x,2}] zeros(1,fill-numel(x))],ran,'UniformOutput',false);
mat = cell2mat(mat(:,:).');
```

Final output:

```
mat =
       8000       15000       15500       16000           0
      16500       14000           0           0           0
       9000       12000       13000           0           0
```

The code is pretty self-explanatory, but if you need clarifications feel free to ask in the comments below.

**EDIT**

```
A = [
  30  6000;
  31  6500;
  32  5000;
  33  8000;
  34 15000;
  35 15500;
  36 16000;
  37  6000;
  38  4000;
  39 16500;
  40 14000;
  41   400;
  42  5000;
  43  6000;
  44  9000;
  45 12000;
  46 13000;
  47  5000
];

B = [
  33 36;
  39 40;
  44 46;
];

fill = 5;

% Obtain the computation parameters from A...
A_len = size(A,1);
A_seq = (1:A_len).';

% Find the breakpoints of A using the values in B...
idx_beg = ismember(A(:,1),B(:,1)) .* A_seq;
idx_beg = idx_beg(idx_beg > 0);
idx_end = ismember(A(:,1),B(:,2)) .* A_seq;
idx_end = idx_end(idx_end > 0);

%Compute the maximum number of elements per row...
rows = max(idx_end - idx_beg + 1);

% Adjust the fill in order to cover enough elements...
fill = max([fill rows]);

% Create the row indexers of A based on the breakpoints...
ran = arrayfun(@(x)idx_beg(x):idx_end(x),1:numel(idx_beg),'UniformOutput',false);

% Create the final matrix with zero-padding on the right...
mat = cellfun(@(x)[A(x,2).' zeros(1,fill-numel(x))],ran,'UniformOutput',false);
mat = cell2mat(mat(:,:).');
```

Comment: Hi @TommasoBelluzzo, thank you for your code! I have tried it with my data and everything works until the point the matrix gets created. I think I should have mentioned, that `A` and `B` both are formatted as `double`. I get the error `Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object.

Error in vector2matrix>@(x)[[A{x,2}],zeros(1,fill-numel(x))]

Error in vector2matrix (line 88)
mat = cellfun(@(x)[[A{x,2}] zeros(1,fill-numel(x))],ran,'UniformOutput',false);`

Comment: Yeah, well... this is probably due to this mismatch... try to replace A{x,2} with A(x,2) and let's hope this can fix it, because I cannot test my script at present.

Comment: Changing `A{x,2}` to `A(x,2)` creates also an error: `Error using horzcat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.

Error in vector2matrix>@(x)[[A(x,2)],zeros(1,fill-numel(x))]

Error in vector2matrix (line 88)
mat = cellfun(@(x)[[A(x,2)] zeros(1,fill-numel(x))],ran,'UniformOutput',false);`

Comment: Your matrix probably has a different orientation. Put on a debugger on the anonymous function and check it.

Comment: Answer edited, it should work with numeric matrices now.

Comment: I fixed that issue with the cell array. But I made a mistake in the description of my problem. `A` and `B` are both formatted as `double`. So the timestamps are num and not string as in your solution. Could this cause the last error? Because when I copy your code everything works fine. But when I have `A` and `B` as `double` and as num, the error above occours. Can you help me with this? I couldn't fix this by myself, yet

Comment: Num? What is a num? The second code snippet deals only with numerical matrices and should work fine. Otherwise, come back when you have an precise idea about the type of data you are manipulating.

Comment: The second code fits perfectly. Thank you very much! And sorry for the confusion with num/string/cell.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for the question. I calculated the difference between the two timestamps of vect B. Then i checked the same timestamp in A and replaced `val` number of variables in M from A(2) and iterated it for all A. Adding The val variable saved from an extra nested for loop where i had to find B(i,2).

```
a=length(A(:,1));
b=length(B(:,1));
M= zeros(5,b);
i=1;

for j=1:a
    if B{i,1} == A{j,1}
        durn_vect=B{i,2}-B{i,1};
        val=durn_vect(4)*600+durn_vect(5)*60+durn_vect(7)*10+durn_vect(8)+1;
        for k=1:val
            M(k,i)=A{j+k-1,2};
        end
        i=i+1;
    end
    if(i>3)
        break
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/350567) by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: This is not Matlab, anyway

Comment: please do check the updated answer. hope it fulfills the criteria. And if it suffices, do remove the downvote as it's discouraging. Also i wrote the prev code on octave online which might be reason of the incorrect syntax.